# SQL Split name into Name and surname

Tags: sql-server

I have table Customers:

```
Name
David Smith
John David
Jonathan Greg
```

and i want to transfer it to table Customers2 :

```
Name      Surname
David     Smith
John      David
Jonathan  Greg
```

How can i split those names into Name/Surname?

Thank you

Comment: Look at CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING.

Comment: What happens if you have an entry like `John Edward Smith`?  Or even `Jane Jones Davis`?

Comment: In addition to @bluefeet's observation (which is a middle name), what about people with 2-part last name like [Dick Van Dyke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dick_Van_Dyke)?

Comment: In my case i have only one name and one surname :)) Czech names are much simpler... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this but a space better be the deliminator...

```
Create table customers2 (
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(Name, ' ', '.'), 2) AS [FirstName],
       PARSENAME(REPLACE(Name, ' ', '.'), 1) AS [LastName]
FROM Customers)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is strictly name + surname, you can do this

```
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE('David Smith', ' ', '.'), 1) AS NAME,
       PARSENAME(REPLACE('David Smith', ' ', '.'), 1) AS SURNAME
```

Comment: wouldn't the first 1 need to be a 2?

Comment: Yes, i think it should be